# Sony SmartWatch Emulator APK

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Im looking for the SmartWatch Emulator APK that I can load on my android phone todo some testing with me being close to my smartwatch.  I recall that I was able to download the APK by itself.  The current SDK docs says its in the APK folder in the SDK distro...but I cannot find that folder on my computer.

Any ideas where I can download the Emulator APK?

Answer (score 2):

Download Sony's SDK as described there

```
http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/
```

then you can find APK you on your disk:

```
<SDK>\add-ons\addon-sony_add-on_sdk_1_0-sony-16\apk_files
```

you may also need to install SmartConnect (aka LiveWare Manager):

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware
```

Comment: Can I install this on an android emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

It's included in the SDK distro (http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/smart-extension-sdk/), in the folder "Smartextension_emulator".

Comment: I just downloaded the SDK from http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk-manual-installation-kit/....I dont see it in the file structure...Is it in a different download?

Comment: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/tool/smart-extension-sdk/ This is the link to the version of the SDK which contains the file structure I referred to. 
Please accept the answer if it solves your issue. Thanks.